# Power script to remove ipp printer

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell, as usual learning by the seat of my pants.

I'm trying to create a script that will look up the ipp printers PortName and then use that to actually delete the printer. The way the ipp printer is being created, you cannot delete the printer via it's Name.  `Remove-Printer -Name "copier"`

I can easily get the PortName using `$printer = Get-Printer -Name copier`
when displaying the variable `$printer.PortName` it gives me just the PortName

The command that worked for deleting the ipp printer is `wmic printer where "PortName = ipp://vsncs1..." delete`

But having a problem injecting the Variable $printer.PortName in place of "ipp://vsncs1..." in the wmic command.

I've tried with different variations.

```
$printer = Get-Printer -Name copier
wmic printer where "PortName like '%$printer.PortName%'" delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use a subexpression:](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)

```
wmic printer where "PortName = '%$($printer.PortName)%'" delete
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Changing the "=" to "like", the printer is deleted.  the "=" was my typo.